# I tried to use postman to post on mongodb but it give me this eror

Tags: mongodb, postman

Hi I want to know how to fix this error. I tried to post data using postman on to mongodb but it give the the following error.

```
{
    "message": "Product validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1\" (type string) at path \"_id\"",
    "stack": "ValidationError: Product validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1\" (type string) at path \"_id\"\n    at model.Document.invalidate (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:2917:32)\n    at model.$set (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:1454:12)\n    at model.$set (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:1149:16)\n    at model.Document (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:158:12)\n    at model.Model (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\model.js:107:12)\n    at new model (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\model.js:4792:15)\n    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\model.js:3336:17)\n    at _start (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\parallelLimit.js:27:37)\n    at parallelLimit (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\parallelLimit.js:23:5)\n    at Function.Model.$__insertMany (D:\\Uni\\SE_Y3\\Semester 1\\Web Programming\\Project code\\Uptown_Book\\server\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\model.js:3366:3)"
}
```

and here are the data i want to post

```
const products = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    name: "Velcro Ballerinas For Girls  (Pink)",
    image: "/images/6.png",
    description:
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
    price: 89,
    countInStock: 3,
    rating: 4,
    numReviews: 4,
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    name: "Velcro Sneakers For Boys & Girls  (Blue)",
    image: "/images/5.png",
    description:
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
    price: 599,
    countInStock: 10,
    rating: 2,
    numReviews: 2,
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    name: "Sesame Street Unisex-Child ELMO Puppet Slipper",
    image: "/images/4.png",
    description:
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
    price: 929,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 3.5,
    numReviews: 3,
  },
  {
    _id: "4",
    name: "Lace Casual Boots For Boys & Girls  (Tan)",
    image: "/images/3.png",
    description:
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
    price: 399,
    countInStock: 10,
    rating: 5,
    numReviews: 9,
  },
  {
    _id: "5",
    name: "Lace Walking Shoes For Boys & Girls  (Pink)",
    image: "/images/2.png",
    description:
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
    price: 49,
    countInStock: 7,
    rating: 2,
    numReviews: 2,
  },
  {
    _id: "6",
    name: "Women Red Heels Sandal",
    image: "/images/1.png",
    description:
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
    price: 29,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  },
];

export default products;
```

I have my port on 5000 and using the command
http://localhost:5000/api/import/products to post but it does not work.

I tried to change the value inside the local file but it still doesn't work

Comment: you need to update your code to accept custom type as `_id` in this case it is string, do that change it will work

Comment: if you don't want to set specific id just remove the `_id` field from json. it will work without any issue